# react-native onChangeText this.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am adding simple masking to a text input, so the date in my DOB field looks like DD/MM/YYYY.

I have a function to handle that:

```
dateFormat(text) {
  if (text.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    this.value = text + '/';
  } else if (text.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    this.value = text + '/';
  }
  this.setState({birthdate: this.value});
}
```

I call this function with:

```
onChangeText={(text) => this.dateFormat(text)}
```

The text is passed correctly. However, this.value is undefined and setting it to whatever, makes no difference.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to reference it as this.value, just declare a var value = text:

```
  onChangeText(text){
    if (text.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
     var value = text + '/';
     this.setState({birthdate: value})
    } else if (text.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
      var value = text + '/';
      this.setState({birthdate: value});
    } else {this.setState({birthdate:text})}
  }
```

I've set it up on RNPlay [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/O9a7XQ), and is seems to be working fine:

https://rnplay.org/apps/O9a7XQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){
    return {
     birthdate: '' 
    }
  },

  onChangeText(text){
    if (text.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
      var value = text + '/';
      this.setState({birthdate: value})
    } else if (text.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        var value = text + '/';
        this.setState({birthdate: value});
    } else {this.setState({birthdate:text})}
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>       
        <TextInput 
          value={this.state.birthdate} 
          onChangeText={ (text) => this.onChangeText(text) } 
          style={styles.textInput} 
          />
        <Text>{this.state.birthdate}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:60
  },
  textInput: {
    height:70,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thank you for reading my question and trying to help. I am new to this, so it could be that I am confused.
I wrote the code the way I did, because I assumed that this.value is bound to the value of the TextInput field, which I want to augment. You just call setState. Does it alter what is presented in the TextInput control? Your code works you say. Great. What does it do, though. Does it create an input mask, or display a value of the masked input over your label? It seems like the latter, which I do not need.

Comment: What this does is change the value of this.state.birthday every time the input value is changed. It does not alter what is presented in the TextInput control. If you want to augment the value bound to the value of the TextInput field, you will just need to add another property to your TextInput like so:

value={this.state.birthdate}

Comment: I've updated both the code example above as well as the example app on RNPlay.

Comment: I will accept the answer, since you are right. It does not immediately help me, as my code, is not working. I have everything that you do, yet it is not working on my 0.17 for whatever reason. Thank you for taking the time.